# How to iterate through a Map in java?

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, iterator, initialization

I need to iterate through a `BucketMap` and get all `keys` but how do I get to something like `buckets[i].next.next.next.key` for instance without doing it manually as I tried here:

```java
public String[] getAllKeys() {
    //index of string array "allkeys"
    int j = 0;
    String allkeys[] = new String[8];
    //iterates through the bucketmap
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {
        //checks wether bucket has a key and value
        if (buckets[i] != null) {
            //adds key to allkeys
            allkeys[j] = buckets[i].key;
            // counts up the allkeys index after adding key
            j++;
            //checks wether next has a key and value
            if (buckets[i].next != null) {
                //adds key to allkeys
                allkeys[j] = buckets[i].next.key;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return allkeys;
}
```

Also how can I initialize the `String[] allkeys` using the version of `j` we get after the iteration is done as the index?

Comment: You could also read the JavaDoc for Map to find out that there's a much easier way to get all keys ...

Comment: Can you give definition of bucket ?

Comment: Well, it's a map. It has a key, a value and next.

Comment: So you can't give the line where 'bucket' is created ... ? You want help or not ? ^^

Comment: `public class KeyValue {
    public String key; 
    public String value; 
    public KeyValue next; // link to next element in same bucket`

Comment: So you have created a kind of LinkedMap ? Why not using existing implementation ?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: You should know that `BucketMap` is not a standard type of map in Java.  So without providing us more details about it, it will be very difficult for us to offer an answer.

Comment: A bucket has a key, a value and a link to the next element in the bucket which also has a key and value and a link and so on.

Comment: so if it's a Map, just get the keySet() and iterate thorughit by for(String key : bucketMap.ketSet()){ /* entry type ex a List, Map, Class etc that is the maps value here*/ ) = bucketMap.get(key) } ie Map<key, List<Value>> would be List<value> = buckeyMap.get(key);

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For basic utilisation, the HashMap is the best, I've put how to iterate over it, easier than using an iterator :

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //a map with key type : String, value type : String
    Map<String,String> mp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    mp.put("John","Math");    mp.put("Jack","Math");    map.put("Jeff","History");

    //3 differents ways to iterate over the map
    for (String key : mp.keySet()){
        //iterate over keys
        System.out.println(key+" "+mp.get(key));
    }

    for (String value : mp.values()){
        //iterate over values
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    for (Entry<String,String> pair : mp.entrySet()){
        //iterate over the pairs
        System.out.println(pair.getKey()+" "+pair.getValue());
    }
}
```

A quick explanation :

```
for (String name : mp.keySet()){
        //Do Something
}
```

means : "For all string from the keys of the map, we'll do something, and at each iteration we will call the key 'name' (it can be whatever you want, it's a variable)

---

Here we go :

```
public String[] getAllKeys(){ 
    int i = 0;
    String allkeys[] = new String[buckets.length];
    KeyValue val = buckets[i];

    //Look at the first one          
    if(val != null) {             
        allkeys[i] = val.key; 
        i++;
    }

    //Iterate until there is no next
    while(val.next != null){
        allkeys[i] = val.next.key;
        val = val.next;
        i++;
    }

    return allkeys;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See if this helps,

```
  HashMap< String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
  Iterator<String> iterator = keySet.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
  {
    //iterate over keys
  }

//or iterate over entryset 
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator2 = map.entrySet().iterator();

while(iterator2.hasNext())
{
    Entry<String, String> next = iterator2.next();
    //get key
    next.getKey();
    //get value
    next.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, I would suggest you to use Stream API.

It will allow you to iterate through the Map in a much more convenient approach:

```
public void iterateUsingStreamAPI(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    map.entrySet().stream()
      // ...
      .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue()));
}
```

Check out for more examples about [iteration through maps in Java](https://javatutorial.net/java-iterate-hashmap-example).