# Map<String, Map<Object, Object>> how to get the value pair dynamically in java

Tags: java, hashmap

Map data structure : `Map<String, Map<Object, Object>>`

Sample data:

```
  Key: Data, Value: {AIA=Yes, AppNumber=15671037, AppType=Utility, RegNumber=P01-010785, Class=714/006.210}
```

From the above, I need to take these Keys`(AIA, AppNumber, AppTYpe, RegNumber)`  dynamically.
for Map I can able to get it, but I don't know in this inner MAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the `Map` corresponding to key `Data`, then take the `keySet()`

```
Map<String, Map<Object, Object>> map = new HashMap<>();  // {Data:{AIA=Yes, AppNumber=15671037, AppType=Utility, RegNumber=P01-010785, Class=714/006.210}}
Map<Object, Object> innerMap = map.get("Data");  // {AIA=Yes, AppNumber=15671037, AppType=Utility, RegNumber=P01-010785, Class=714/006.210}
Set<Object> keysInnerMap = innerMap.keySet();   // {AIA, AppNumber, AppTYpe, RegNumber}
```

Comment: thanks, let me know how can I get the value of the each key. I tried iterator but no luck

Comment: @Prabu `innerMap.get("AIA")` or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015098/how-to-iterate-through-a-map-in-java/43015629#43015629 to get all

Answer (score 0):

Iterate all the values of the Outer Map then add the keys of Inner map in a list.

```
List<Object> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Map<Object, Object> innerMap : map.values()) {
    keyList.addAll(innerMap.keySet());
}
```